# wintypes.dcu not found and code completion stops working

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009

I'm getting the error: wintypes.dcu not found several times a day in the Delphi 2009 IDE, after this error code completion stops working, also I can't open any unit's source code with Ctrl + Click, then I have to reopen the IDE to fix it.

Anyone has a clue about what can be causing this?

The only IDE extension I have installed is GExperts.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

wintypes.pas and winprocs.pas has been replaced with windows.pas (since a long time). You should use Unit Aliases to replace all wintypes with windows.

Comment: No, fix it in the source. E.g. Free Pascal/Lazarus don't support unit aliases, and D2009 code is usually not D1 compatible anyway, if only  because of unicode. It is slowly time to kill this beast.

Answer (score 7):

You must be still using the ancient (pre-Delphi 2) names for what is now the Windows unit. I recommend that you search and replace all your uses lists and replace WinTypes and WinProcs with Windows.

Alternatively, you can make sure you have "WinTypes=Windows" and "WinProcs=Windows" in the Unit Aliases section of your project options, but still, after all these decades, I'd move on to the 32-bit world! (16-bit being the prime limitation that meant WinTypes and WinProcs were two separate units.)

Comment: Well, it just speaks volume for Delphi backward compatibility as this must be very ancient Delphi1 code! I don't think people would even think of compiling old MS code into Visual Studio now... You guys did such a good job, Delphi developers got spoiled ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Open Project - Options, Delphi Compiler ,into Unit aliases insert:

WinTypes=Windows;WinProcs=Windows;DbiProcs=BDE;DbiTypes=BDE;DbiErrs=BDE

Answer (score 1):

Do you use the Decision Cube component? So look for references on the unit MXQEDCOM.pas in your sources.

On BDS 2006, is the only reference for Wintypes and Winprocs I found.

By the way, make sure that the Unit Aliases included the values that [Barry Kelly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/284091/wintypesdcu-not-found-and-code-completion-stops-working#284290) wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Why wintypes.dcu cannot be found any longer, I do not know. But the other two are obvious follow up errors: if Delphi cannot compile the code due to syntax errors (and a missing file is considered a syntax error), it stops code completion and cannot locate source code any longer using Ctrl + Click.